# Deriving a simple relationship between the PSD of $x(t)$ and the PSD of its square $x^2(t)$, assuming $x(t)$ is a white noise

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density

Let $x(t)$ be a discrete time random process exhibiting a Gaussian density and a white noise, and a zero mean value.

I am interested in deriving $S_{x^2}(f)$, the Power Spectral Density of $x^2(t)$, as a function of  $S_{x}(f)$, the PSD of $x(t)$.

Is there any simple relationship between these two, using the white noise nature of $x(t)$?

I would expect something like $S_{x^2}(f) \propto |S_{x}(f)|^2$, since this is what I get from a very basic Matlab simulation with the **wgn** function (white gaussian noise), but for now I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a function $y(t) = |x(t)|^2$, where $x(t)$ is a zero-mean Gaussian white noise process, the result $|x(t)|^2$ will no longer be Gaussian distributed but it will still be white (once the mean is removed as Dilip points out in the comments.  The fact that it is white once the mean is removed can be proven by the autocorrelation function or by simply noting that for a sampled white noise process, each sample will be independent of the next, squaring such a process does not create any dependence or memory between samples other than the mean. Given Parseval's theorem, $\sigma_x^2 = \sigma_X^2$, so $S_{X^2}(f) \propto |S_{X}(f)|^2$.

To prove this we note that the power spectral density (PSD) is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function. For white noise processes the autocorrelation is an impulse at $\tau=0$ which has a Fourier Transform as a constant for all frequencies. The autocorrelation at $\tau=0$ is the variance of the time domain function, so for the special case of white noise $x(t)$, the Fourier Transform $X(f)= \sigma_x^2$.   The autocorrelation function of $|x(t)|^2$ would therefore be the variance of $|x(t)|^2$ which for real $x(t)$ is $2(\sigma_x^2)^2$ and for complex $x(t)$ is $(\sigma_x^2)^2$ as:

$$\text{Var} x^2 =\text{E} x^4-(\text{E}x^2)^2 = \text{E} x^4-(\sigma_x^2)^2$$

$$\text{E} x^4 = 3\sigma_x^4$$
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917647/proving-ex4-3%CF%834))

Where $\text{Var}$ is the variance and $\text{E}$ is the expected value.

so
$$\text{Var} x^2 = 2\sigma_x^4$$

The PSD of $y(t) = |x(t)|^2$ in this case of a stationary real Gaussian white noise process $x(t)$ would therefore be $2(S_X(f))^2$ and $(S_X(f))^2$ when $x(t)$ is complex.

For the complex case we note that the real and imaginary components of $x(t)$ are each identically distributed independent Gaussian white noise processes each having a variance $\text{Var } \text{Real}(x) = \text{Var } \text{Imag}(x) =  \sqrt{2}\sigma_x^2$ and therefore in this case $$\text{Var} x^2 = \sigma_x^4$$

In general, the PSD given as $S_X(f)$ typically refers to the **one-sided** power spectral density in magnitude-squared units of the time domain variable as a density per Hz meaning the power within a 1 Hz bandwidth of spectrum. For example, if $x(t)$ was phase versus time, typically given as $\phi(t)$ in units of radians, then we would have $S_\phi(t)$ in units of $\text{rad}^2/\text{Hz}$, as a one-sided phase noise PSD. This would be the power spectral density due to phase fluctuations of the signal over time. You can replace $\phi$ with any variable $x$ to have the power spectral density due to "x" fluctuations with time.  A one-sided PSD implies that $x(t)$ has a symmetric power spectrum and thus we can provide just one-side of the spectrum as simply twice the two-sided spectrum.  This applies regardless of the type of noise on $x$, as long as a power spectral density exists (meaning $x(t)$ is stationary). Whether the process is white noise or otherwise will be clear from an observation of the power spectral density (with white noise having a constant PSD).

To be clear let's look at an example using white  noise as shown in the graphic below. $h_x$ represents the magnitude of the power spectral density, which for white noise would be constant and as a density represents the power quantity within a 1 Hz bandwidth of the spectrum. In signal processing, "power" is simply the magnitude squared of the time domain variable:

[image: white noise]

Comment: Since $|x(t)|^2$ has nonzero mean, its power spectral density _should_ have an impulse at the origin instead of being $2(S_X(f))^2$ which is just as flat $S_X(f)$ is. So, calling $|x(t)|^2$ as _white noise_ (albeit nonGaussian) is still a stretching of the concept of white noise.  Also, one would expect white noise to have a distribution that is symmetric about $0$, which $|x(t)|^2$ very definitely does not have.  So, please include in your answer what _you_ understand as the properties of white noise to be (or what properties _a _ noise must have to deserve the soubriquet of "white"). Thanks.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I didn’t say the result was zero mean- but it’s a good distinction- I will clarify that - thanks

Comment: Once the mean is removed it has all the properties we would associate with white noise: constant PSD, and autocorrelation function is an impulse.

Comment: Thank you both for your input! Just to follow up on this aspect, even when you remove the mean, $x^2(t)$ does not exhibit the gaussian density that $x(t)$ has. It is very packed on the lower side obviously. Is this a problem for your demonstration ?

Comment: Right it is certainly no longer Gaussian (if x(t) was complex it would be Rayleigh). I confirmed that the result matches a simulation for the predicted variance and that excluding DC the PSD is constant.

Comment: "Once the mean is removed, it has all the properties for what we would associate with white noise:"  and that is where I beg to differ.  The noise has very _asymmetrical_ distribution regardless of whether the mean has been subtracted off or not, and so even though the demeaned noise has constant power spectral density, it is not what some would characterize as _white_ noise; we can confidently predict that the noise cannot take on values smaller than $-\alpha$ for some $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I didn’t know the distribution was required to be symmetrical for the spectrum to be white- I associate any random process with a constant spectral density as “white” associated with light of all colors. We can have different distributions and still have white noise for example quantization noise is well approximated as a uniform white noise process.

Comment: This is consistent with Wikipedia’s definition of white noise where there it states “Any distribution of values is possible (although it must have zero DC component.” and gives the criteria I supplied as to what would count as “white noise”. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise. Do you have another reference that actually sets a requirement on the amplitude distribution in time?